# Integrating QuickBooks with Web App. Which way to go?

Tags: api, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml

I have QuickBooks Enterprise 14 and I'm looking at the best way to integrate data (pulling/pushing Invoice/PO/Customer) between QB and our internal web app (.NET C#). Looking at Intuit documentations I see there are 2 ways? Intuit Partner Platform with QuickBooks REST API or use WebConnector and qbXML? Which is the better way to go? It seems using QuickBooks REST API would be better but my boss is "concerned" about the "Partner" in the IPP as we are not planning to sell this. Is this term being use loosely by Intuit or it's really meant for partner that wants to sell Apps on Intuit market?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For QBD custom solution, you should QBSDK WebConnector tool.

Ref -https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq#What_types_of_applications_are_supported_with_QuickBooks_API.3F

Thanks

Comment: After the webinar with the IPP team today, I would probably suggest the same thing.  Although the IPP team will tell you that the SDK is the way to go... I think I would disagree, though I am not too familiar with either of them.

Answer (score 0):

Things are changing - the new direction from Intuit is going to be that if you are developing for the desktop, use the SDK (and Web Connector in your case). IPP won't be an option going forward, for integration with the Desktop products.

Comment: See my article on this at http://www.sleeter.com/blog/2013/11/quickbooks-software-integration/

Answer (score 0):

Things are definitely changing, as Charlie said, I would suggest tuning in to the webinar happening tomorrow.  You can find the link in an answer that Charlie gave on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862347/is-quickbooks-api-qbd-v3-really-deprecated).  It really seems that Intuit is starting to move away from the desktop software completely, which I get, but they are currently not saying much about what will actually be supported in the near future.